# Declaring variable in FOR loop

Tags: c++, loops, declare

I know in C++ that you can declare on variables inside the FOR, e.g:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

is there any way to declare another variables inside the for? this won't work for me:

```
for(int i=0, char Ch='J'; i<10; i++)
```

Comment: Yes, edited.. meant another type, like a class I've made or something.

Comment: no you can t! only same type..

Answer (score 9):

You could use a `std::pair`:

```
for (std::pair<int, char> p(0, 'j'); p.first < 10; p.first++)
{
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution would be to make a scope just outside the `for`:

```
{
    char Ch = 'j';

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am intrigued as to why this was downvoted, since it is actually the right answer.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot.  You can do it this way:

```
char Ch='J';
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

The problem is that to declare a variable of a different type, you need a semicolon (`;`) to separate the two statements -- the comma (`,`) declares a variable of the same type.  But the semicolon has a different meaning in the `for` header.

If you are concerned about the scope, you can enclose it in a block as well.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, you can declare only one type inside a foor loop. The type can be a struct, though, so there's a weird hack around the restriction:

```
int main()
{
    for (struct {int i; char c; } s = {0, 'A'};
         s.i < 26; ++s.i, ++s.c) {
            std::cout << s.c;  // prints the alphabet
         }
}
```

But that's something you shouldn't really do, just declare the variables you need before the loop :)

```
int main()
{
   {
    int i = 0;
    char c = 'A';

    for (; i < 10; ++i) { /* ...*/ }
   }
}
```

Note the extra set of parantheses - you can use them to restrict the scope of variables if the names would otherwise clash with variables from the surrounding scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare another variable but only of the same type, the following works:

```
  for(int i=0, Ch='J'; i<10; i++)
```

But `Ch` will now be an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
Between `;` you can do anything can be done with `,`, so the following is possible:

```
for(int i=0, j=10; i<5; ++i,--j) { ... }
```

but if you need variables with different types, this cannot be done being the `;` required to separate the sub-declarations.

Note that even C++11 auto doesn't help:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(auto i=0, c = "abcd"; i<3; ++i,++c)
        cout << *c;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

result in a compilation error:

```
inconsistent deduction for 'auto': 'int' and then 'const char*'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ",".

```
for(int i=0,x=0; i<x; i++)
...
```

I would say that int i=0 is executed outside of the loop... the definition of i is executed before entering the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can't re-declare the data type for the other variables, try this instead:

```
   for(int i = 0, j = 10; i < x; i++) {}
```